# QCustomPlot : get axis pixel size

Tags: qcustomplot

Does anyone knows how to get the axis pixel size from a QCustomPlot axis ?

Currently I'm using

> plot->yAxis->axisRect()->width();

But this doesn't give me the right value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use coordToPixel():

```
double tickInPixelY =  customPlot->yAxis->coordToPixel(0)-customPlot->yAxis->coordToPixel(1);
```

It find one tick in pixels;